# Flutter - Is there a way to list all of the streams in an app

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

Is there a way to list all the streams that an app is using or that can be listened to or subscribed to?

Comment: To see what streams are available to be listened to.  To see what streams have already been constructed.  Some of the libraries create streams, so this is not obvious.

Comment: there is no way to get such a list, sorry